Field not created in mongoDB
I'm am making a post request, where the schema includes a creator field like this
import { Schema, model, models } from 'mongoose';

const PromptSchema = new Schema({
  
  prompt: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Prompt is required.'],
  },
  tag: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Tag is required.'],
  },
  creator: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
  }
});

const Prompt = models.Prompt || model('Prompt', PromptSchema);

export default Prompt;

the new prompts route in the api is as follows:
import { connectToDB } from "@utils/database";
import Prompt from "@models/prompt";

export const POST = async (req) => {
    const {userId, prompt, tag} = await req.json();
    try {
        await connectToDB()
        const newPrompt = new Prompt({
            prompt, 
            tag,
            creator: userId
        })
        await newPrompt.save();
        return new Response(JSON.stringify(newPrompt), {status: 201})
    } catch (error) {
        return new Response('failed to create a new prompt', {status: 500})
    }
}

The post is being created in the database, but without the creator field:
{"_id": 
{"$oid":"66ed2175514674df2b293ca0"},"prompt":"dandiidida","tag":"#testing","__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}}

I've tried calling _id instead of creator in my "populate" function to get all post, image and username but it's not returning them.

Verify the type of userId as in creator: userId.  It is likely the POST request converted that to a string, so you may have to convert it back to ObjectId to match the schema
